# R boxplot add cut off

Tags: r, addition, boxplot

I'm using `boxplot` and then `add` to create a set of side by side comparisons.  However the last box is cut in half.  See below:

[image: Cut off boxplot]

Here's the code I'm using:

```
boxplot(mydf$Prop ~ mydf$Id,at=c(1,4,7))
boxplot(mydf$Prop2 ~ mydf$Id,at=c(2,5,8),add = TRUE)
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to adjust the `xlim` parameter so that it makes room for the addition to the plot:

```
boxplot(mydf$Prop ~ mydf$Id,at=c(1,4,7),xlim=c(0.5,8.5))
boxplot(mydf$Prop2 ~ mydf$Id,at=c(2,5,8),add = TRUE)
```

As an alternative, you can adjust your dataframe slightly and use `ggplot2` so that you don't have to worry about adding to your plot and adjusting the limits:

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

df <- melt(mydf,id.var="Id")
df$Id <- as.factor(df$Id)

ggplot(df,aes(x=Id,y=value,group=interaction(variable,Id),fill=variable))+
  geom_boxplot(width=0.45,position=position_dodge(width=0.5))+theme_bw()+
  labs(fill="")
```

[image]

The downside is learning a new graphing paradigm and sometimes longer calls, but you may find there's a large upside.